# Get value from JToken that may not exist (best practices)

Tags: c#, json.net

What's the best practice for retrieving JSON values that may not even exist in C# using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com)?

Right now I'm dealing with a JSON provider that returns JSON that sometimes contains certain key/value pairs, and sometimes does not. I've been using (perhaps incorrectly) this method to get my values (example for getting a double):

```
if(null != jToken["width"])
    width = double.Parse(jToken["width"].ToString());
else
    width = 100;
```

Now that works fine, but when there are a lot of them it's cumbersome. I ended up writing an extension method, and only *after* writing it did I wonder whether maybe I was being stupid... anyways, here is the extension method (I only include cases for double and string, but in reality I have quite a few more):

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this JToken jToken, string key,
                            T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    T returnValue = defaultValue;

    if (jToken[key] != null)
    {
        object data = null;
        string sData = jToken[key].ToString();

        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (type is double)
            data = double.Parse(sData);
        else if (type is string)
            data = sData;

        if (null == data && type.IsValueType)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot parse type \"" + 
                type.FullName + "\" from value \"" + sData + "\"");

        returnValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(data, 
            type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

And here's an example of using the extension method:

```
width = jToken.GetValue<double>("width", 100);
```

BTW, Please forgive what may be a really dumb question, since it seems like something there should be a built in function for... I did try Google, and [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) documentation, however I'm either inept at finding the solution to my question or it's not clear in the documentation.

Comment: I know it is a bit late, but you may want to try this simplified version of `GetValue` below

Comment: `string rootValue = jToken.Value<string>()`

Answer (score 260, accepted):

This is pretty much what the generic method [`Value()`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) is for. You get exactly the behavior you want if you combine it with nullable value types and the `??` operator:

```
width = jToken.Value<double?>("width") ?? 100;
```

Comment: This doesn't work if "width" doesn't exists in the json and JToken is null

Comment: @Deepak It does work if "width" doesn't exist. Of course it doesn't work if `jToken` is `null`, but that's not what the question asked. And you can easily fix that by using the null conditional operator: `width = jToken?.Value<double?>("width") ?? 100;`.

Comment: `JToken.Value<T>` throws an exception if the JToken is a JValue

Comment: To handle casing: `string ver = ((JObject)token).GetValue("version", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>();` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886682/2874896

Comment: Like @KyleDelaney notes this code is dangerous.  Will throw  `InvalidOperationException` in cases when `JToken` type ([`JTokenType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtokentype.htm)) is one of `JValue`  or `Undefined` or `Null`

Answer (score 24):

I would write `GetValue` as below

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this JToken jToken, string key, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    dynamic ret = jToken[key];
    if (ret == null) return defaultValue;
    if (ret is JObject) return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(ret.ToString());
    return (T)ret;
}
```

This way you can get the value of not only the basic types but also complex objects. Here is a sample

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int I;
    public double D;
    public ClassB ClassB;
}
public class ClassB
{
    public int I;
    public string S;
}

var jt = JToken.Parse("{ I:1, D:3.5, ClassB:{I:2, S:'test'} }");

int i1 = jt.GetValue<int>("I");
double d1 = jt.GetValue<double>("D");
ClassB b = jt.GetValue<ClassB>("ClassB");
```

Comment: That is pretty cool, but I like the separation of concerns that only getting simple data types gives me. Although the notion of that separation is a little bit blurred when it comes to JSON parsing. Since I implement an observer / observable model (with mvvm as well), I tend to keep all my parsing in one place, and keep it simple (part of that is also the unpredictability of the data returned to me).

Comment: @PaulHazen I can not say that I understand you. Your question was `retrieving JSON values that may not even exist` and all I proposed was to change your `GetValue` method. I think it works as how you want

Comment: Hopefully I can be a little more clear this time. Your method works great, and would accomplish exactly what I want. However, the greater context not explained in my question is that the particular code I'm working on is code that I want to be highly transferable. While it's arguable that your method gets in the way, it introduces the ability to deserialize objects from GetValue<T>, which is a pattern I want to avoid for the sake of moving my code to a platform that has a better JSON parser (say, Win8 for example). So, for what I asked, yes, your code would be perfect.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you can check if the token exists:

```
if (jobject["Result"].SelectToken("Items") != null) { ... }
```

It checks if "Items" exists in "Result".

This is a NOT working example that causes exception:

```
if (jobject["Result"]["Items"] != null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply typecast, and it will do the conversion for you, e.g.

```
var with = (double?) jToken[key] ?? 100;
```

It will automatically return `null` if said key is not present in the object, so there's no need to test for it.

Answer (score 4):

This takes care of nulls

```
var body = JObject.Parse("anyjsonString");

body?.SelectToken("path-string-prop")?.ToString();

body?.SelectToken("path-double-prop")?.ToObject<double>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`TYPE variable = jsonbody["key"]?.Value<TYPE>() ?? DEFAULT_VALUE;`

e.g.

`bool attachMap = jsonbody["map"]?.Value<bool>() ?? false;`