# JSON.NET JToken Keys Are Case Sensitive?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having to perform some custom deserialization with JSON.NET and I just found that it's treating the key values in a JToken as case sensitive. Here's some code:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
     JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
     JToken version = token["version"];

     string ver = version.ToObject<string>();

     return new MyVersion(ver);
}
```

The `version` variable is null even though the json contains a version element at the top level, it's just in upper case:

```
{
    "VERSION" : "1.0",
    "NAME" : "john smith"
}
```

Is there any way to use `JToken` with case-insensitive keys? Or maybe another approach without `JToken` that lets me grab and deserialize individual properties?

EDIT:

Based on the comments I ended up doing this:

```
JObject token = JObject.Load(reader);
string version = token.GetValue("version", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToObject<string>(serializer);
```

Comment: Yes, they are.  But see [JSON.NET JObject key comparison case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475542) for a workaround.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can cast JToken to JObject and do this:

```
string ver = ((JObject)token).GetValue("version", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert JToken to JObject and use TryGetValue method of JObject in which you can specify String Comparision.

```
 var jObject = JToken.Load(reader) as JObject;
 JToken version;
 jObject.TryGetValue("version", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, out version);
```